# How to extract CSRF cookie from request and send into HTTP Request without using parameter in JMeter

Tags: parameters, request, jmeter, csrf

I am new to JMeter. I am performing login test. I am trying to extract CSRF token but i don't get it. I don't know how to resolve it.

[request data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQnjK.png)

[regular expression extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odqbP.jpg)

When i try to put CSRF token - "reference name" into HTTP Request - "Parameters" i got the error.

[HTTP Request - Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4bu5.png)

I am stuck here. I don't know how to put CSRF token - "reference name" without "Parameters". Please help me.

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but that token in the cookie does not provide any protection against csrf, and there is no parameter to implement double posting. :) (Or maybe we can't see post parameters? I don't know JMeter.)

Answer (score 0):

To send parameter in POST request with JSON body you can add parameters in Path field after ? Sign, in your case add

```
?csrf=${token}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  you should navigate with a browser, analyse the 
traffic and mimick it.

Chrome has a tool to do it or you can use Fiddler.
Generally speaking, CSRF is returned as cookie from the server the first time, then it must be returned both as a cookie and in the header.

Sometime the value changes, even in the same session.
Be aware of this.

So you must:

- insert a cookie manager (at top level in the project)
- extract the value from the response header (every time it changes)
- insert it as a header parameter in all the following requests

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of extracting a cookie into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) is using [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

1. Add HTTP Cookie Manager to your Test Plan
2. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   CookieManager.save.cookies=false
   ```
3. Restart JMeter to pick the property up

When the cookie will come from the server you will be able to access it as `${COOKIE_csrftoken}` where required.

More information: [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide)